# Multipart form upload to S3 using libcurl and CURLFORM_STREAM

Tags: c, http, https, amazon-s3, libcurl

I am trying to upload in C/C++ code to S3 using libcurl. I am uploading binary data to be generated from a callback.

I've been staring at this for a while, so I may be way off :( but here is what my code looks like right now:

First, I build my form like so:

```
struct curl_httppost *buildForm(void *streamData, long contentLength) {
   struct curl_httppost *formpost=NULL;
   struct curl_httppost *lastptr=NULL;
   for( int i=0; i<form.size(); ++i ) {
     curl_formadd(&formpost,
           &lastptr,
           CURLFORM_COPYNAME, form[i].first.c_str(),
           CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, form[i].second.c_str(),
           CURLFORM_END);
  }
  curl_formadd(&formpost,
           &lastptr,
           CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "file",
           CURLFORM_STREAM, streamData,
           CURLFORM_CONTENTSLENGTH, (long) contentLength,
           CURLFORM_FILENAME, "chunk",
           //CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE, "application/octet-stream",
           CURLFORM_END);
  return formpost;
}
```

Then I setup the request like this:

```
  curl_easy_reset( handle );
  struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
  headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Expect:");
  curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
  curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L );
  curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION, curlDebugger );
  curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_URL, postInstructions.url.c_str() );
  curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);

  // set the data and header read callbacks:
  curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, &(UploadCallback::writeDataStatic));
  curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);
  //I have tried with and without this line
  curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)contentLength);
  curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &(XonamiResponse::readDataStatic));
  curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
  curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, &(XonamiResponse::readHeaderStatic));
  curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, &response);

  // do it!
  int success = curl_easy_perform( handle );
```

However, curl complains:

```
  operation aborted by callback
```

even though I am generating the same number of bytes as contentLength. When I setup my callback to just fill the buffers with zero as long as data is requested, S3 responds with:

```
  The body of your POST request is not well-formed multipart/form-data.
```

and looking at the raw form it looks to me like the last (closing) boundary is missing.

curl --version says:

curl 7.19.7 (universal-apple-darwin10.0) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.3
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap http file https ftps 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is in my callback which was inadvertently returning abort instead of CURL_READFUNC_ABORT when it was done. Oops.